# 404 error on valid URL from Servlet

Tags: java, jsf

I have a project due (actually overdo) for school and cannot get something simple working.

I am running Netbeans 7.2.1, Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and the latest Java JDK.

I have four JSF pages, index.xhtml ItemAdd.xhtml, ItemCatalog.xhtml, and ItemDetail.xhtml and a servlet SessionServlet.  I have verified that I can directly reach each of the pages  i.e

```
http://localhost:8080/CMIS440Spitzer-Project2/faces/ItemDetail.xhtml
```

works. However when I go from one of the JSF pages to my servlet and then forward the request on I get a glassfish 404 error.

Here is my extremely simple  servlet code that is doing the forwarding:

```
if (request.getParameter("target").contains("Add Item")) {
        String URL = request.getContextPath() + "/faces/ItemAdd.xhtml";
        System.out.print(URL);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(URL);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

One the console I get the following which I can paste into my browser and it works:

```
INFO: /CMIS440Spitzer-Project2/faces/ItemAdd.xhtml
```

Since I get the console message I know the request is reaching the servlet and that it is hitting the right code block and because I get a  Glassfish 404 error I know it is forwarding to my machine on the correct port.

What is the issue with the RequestDispatcher? Why is this not working?

Thanks.

```
<rant>
```

This encompases more then this issue but I have worked with PHP, perl, C++, C, Java and a few others. NEVER before have I felt that a language (in this case the JSF implementation of Java) was actively trying to make my life as difficult as possible. For example, many needed things in this environment is in the form of maps:
Need a list of all request parameters, you get a map, need a list of all session parameters, you get a map, etc. However in JSF you cannot easily LOOP THROUGH MAPS! Why, because it is slow. I found a link that was basically a Mea Culpa from a Java developer who mentioned it would be O(N) speed so it would be slow. In other word the Java JSF developers pre-optimized my code and require me to convert maps to lists.

At one point in this I was getting some weird error regarding reflection and accessing private methods/properties when now-where in my code was I doing anything of the kind. I was using standard getters/setters to return a map keyset.

Dont even get me started on the naming conventions of getters/setters (uppercase converted to lowercase, add a get/set in front)

Maybe its me but this whole setup seems overly obtuse,hard to understand and unnecessarily complicated.

Thanks for reading my rant. I have been at this WAY longer then I thought I should and have been nearly to tears trying to do simple stuff.

```
</rant>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing servlets for session management and JSF pages? when working with JSF, you have to stop thinking in terms of the http request/response paradigm, it's an event-driven framework with more in common to desktop GUI programming. Granted, JSF is *not* the friendliest web framework to work with, but you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Because I don't know any better and this is how the instructors basic examples work :-)

Comment: @user1863569 I'm sorry, but you're using this technology in the wrong way, leading to lots of unnecessary frustration. You are better off googling for a tutorial and running a hello world example first, so you can get your bearings

Comment: My problem is many of the examples floating around either use script let's or jsf 1.x.. Maybe I missed the point of the mvc 2 paradigm but I thought it that's what the controller did: take the results of a form,  do some processing of model data then forward it on to a new view

Comment: @user1863569 that's right, but JSF comes with its own controller: `FacesServlet`. Many of the old web-tier patterns are already built in the framework. Each JSF page takes care of validation, conversion and all data ends up in a backing bean Java object, without ever having to think about request parameters, servlets, http get/post, etc.

Comment: @user1863569 and by the way, please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 0):

The path you pass to [`getRequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) is relative to the context root.

By adding the context path to it, you're ending up with `/CMIS440Spitzer-Project2/CMIS440Spitzer-Project2/faces/ItemAdd.xhtml`, which doesn't exist.

(Actually, it's relative to the context root if it starts with a slash, as this one does.  If it doesn't start with a slash it's relative to the servlet.)

Comment: <D'oh> The extremely frustrating thing is I found multiple examples of this exact same pattern in examples. Additionally, why doesn't the Glassfish 404 error tell you what path isn't available? If I had seen that I could have figured it out myself.

Comment: @user1863569, you should be able to create a custom error page that can provide you with this and other useful debugging information.  As to why Glassfish doesn't tell you about it by default... I suppose it might be considered a security risk (information disclosure of the internal structure of the webapp).

Comment: Because programming is hard. The tools are not going to do the work for you, its all you. One of the responsibilities you have here is to know -exactly- how this technology works. When you do you don't need to wonder anymore, you just know and when you don't know you know where to look to find out.

Comment: @user1863569, if this is the 'correct' answer please click the checkmark on the left.  If not, let me know what's missing so I can correct it.  Thanks.